# What are some good java image processing tools or APIs?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, file-upload, imagemagick

I want to build an upload applet / desktop client that can resize - trim and then send an image to my amazon s3 bucket.

Trimming my images has proven to take the longest and be the most cpu intensive. On my server when a user uploads a image using an html form I use imagemagick command line tools to do the trim and resize.

What tools would you guys recommend using?

Edit: I need to be able to automatically crop images. Something similar to the imagemagick trim function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you check out JAI.

Specifically check out the classes [CropDescriptor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/CropDescriptor.html), [ScaleDescriptor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/ScaleDescriptor.html) and their static methods.

Also, take a look at the subclasses of [OperationDescriptorImpl](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/OperationDescriptorImpl.html), they will give you an idea of the types of operations JAI is capable of.